# Access Violation during iteration of multiple drives

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, vector

Am working in a project where i have to iterate through a set drives given as a input to list the files present in it.i implemented it with windows threads and stores the set of files in a vector.It is working perfectly if i give a single drive as an input.but when trying to iterate multiple drives it shows "Unhandled exception at 0x5efaad4a (msvcp100d.dll) in ListTest.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xdddddde1." I tries debugging the program but the error appears at random locations in my program.I really don't know where is the error exactly in my program,Since it is working perfectly for single drive.

MultiDrive List.h

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <vector>




namespace DriveFiles
{
    struct List
    {
         //std::string *scr ;
         std::vector<std::string>files[10];
    };  

    class FileList
    {
        //static const int MAX_THREADS = 3 ;
    public:
        //static vector<std::string>fil;
        //struct List *list;
        static void ListFiles(std::string DriveId);
        static DWORD WINAPI ParThread(LPVOID s);
        static DWORD WINAPI Listing(LPVOID s);
        //static void display(std::vector<std::string>&files);
    };
}
```

MultiDriveListing.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <deque>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include "MultiDrive List.h"

using namespace std;
CRITICAL_SECTION QueueLock;
CRITICAL_SECTION StoreLock;
//CRITICAL_SECTION FileLock;
#define MAX_THREADS 2
HANDLE Child[MAX_THREADS];
deque<string>directories;
//vector<string>files;
int Files = 0;
struct DriveFiles::List *list = new struct DriveFiles::List();

namespace DriveFiles
{

        void FileList :: ListFiles(string DriveId)
        {   
            DWORD threadid; 
            vector<string> v; 
            string buf; 


            stringstream ss(DriveId); 
            //InitializeCriticalSection(&FileLock);
            InitializeCriticalSection(&QueueLock);
            InitializeCriticalSection(&StoreLock);

            cout << " List Will be in file form in few Sec " << endl;

            directories.clear();
            list->files[0].clear();
             while (ss >> buf)
                v.push_back(buf);
            HANDLE *Parent = new HANDLE[v.size()];
            string *scr;
            scr = new string[v.size()];
            //list->scr = new string[v.size()];
            for(int i=0; i<v.size(); i++)
            {
                scr[i]= v[i];
            }
            //cout << "no of drives "<<v.size();
            //list = HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(),0,sizeof(List));
            long t1 = GetTickCount();
            for(int i=0;i<v.size();i++)
            {
                 Parent[i] = CreateThread(NULL,0,ParThread,(LPVOID)scr[i].c_str(),0,&threadid);
            }
            WaitForMultipleObjects(v.size(),Parent,TRUE,INFINITE);
            //display();
            cout<< "Execution Time " <<GetTickCount()-t1;
            v.clear();
            //return files;
        }


        DWORD WINAPI FileList :: ParThread(LPVOID s)
        {
            DWORD threadid;
            WIN32_FIND_DATAA ffd;
            //cout << "in parent" <<endl;
             //struct List *x;

            char *drive =(char*)s;
            string path = drive;
            cout<<drive;
            //vector<string>fil;
            //list->files[0] = fil;
            string spec = path + "\\" + "*";

            HANDLE hFind = FindFirstFileA(spec.c_str(), &ffd);

             if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == hFind) 
             {
                     cout << "FindFirstFile error";
             }
                //cout<<"List of Folders in Drive"<<endl;
            do
            {
                 if(!strcmp(ffd.cFileName, "..") == 0 && !strcmp(ffd.cFileName, ".") == 0)
                {
                    if (ffd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY )
                    {   
                        EnterCriticalSection(&QueueLock);
                         directories.push_back( path + "\\" + ffd.cFileName );
                         LeaveCriticalSection(&QueueLock);
                         //cout << ffd.cFileName <<endl;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        EnterCriticalSection(&StoreLock);
                        list->files[0].push_back( path + "\\" + ffd.cFileName );
                        Files++;
                        LeaveCriticalSection(&StoreLock);
                    }


                 }
            }while (FindNextFileA(hFind, &ffd) != 0);
            FindClose(hFind);
            /*fstream out;
            EnterCriticalSection(&FileLock);
            out.open("List.txt",ios_base::out | ios_base::app );
            vector<string>::iterator it = fil.begin();
            if(fil.size()!=0)
            do
            {
                //cout << "Writing to .txt File ";
                out<<*it<<endl;
                *it++;
            }while(it!=fil.end());
            out.close();
            fil.clear();
            LeaveCriticalSection(&FileLock);*/
            //DeleteCriticalSection(&QueueLock);
            //cout << endl<<list->files[0].size();
            cout << endl<<"No of Files "<<Files;
            for(int i=0;i<MAX_THREADS;i++)
            {
                 Child[i] = CreateThread(NULL,0,Listing,(LPVOID)&list->files[i],0,&threadid);
                 //cout<<endl<<list->files[i+1].size();
                 if( Child[i] == NULL )
                 {
                    printf("CreateThread error: %d\n", GetLastError());
                     return 0;
                 }
            }

             WaitForMultipleObjects(MAX_THREADS,Child,TRUE,INFINITE);
             return 0;
        }
        DWORD WINAPI FileList :: Listing(LPVOID s)
        {

            deque<string>subdir;

            string path = " ";
            string spec = " ";
            string subpath = " ";
            int Files = 0;
            //vector<string>files;
            vector<string>*file;

            file = (vector<string>*)s;
            WIN32_FIND_DATAA ffd;
            //InitializeCriticalSection(&QueueLock);


            while(true)     
            {
                        EnterCriticalSection(&QueueLock);
                        if(directories.empty())
                        {
                            LeaveCriticalSection(&QueueLock);
                            //Sleep(500);
                            break;
                    }
                        else
                        {
                            path = directories.front();
                            directories.pop_front();
                            spec = path + "\\" + "*";
                            LeaveCriticalSection(&QueueLock);
                            subdir.push_front(path);
                        }
                        while(!subdir.empty())
                        {
                            subpath = subdir.front();
                            spec = subpath + "\\" + "*";
                            subdir.pop_front();

                            HANDLE hfind = FindFirstFileA(spec.c_str(),&ffd);
                            if(hfind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
                                    continue;
                            cout << subpath << endl;
                            do
                            {
                                if(strcmp(ffd.cFileName,".") && strcmp(ffd.cFileName,".."))
                                {
                                    if(ffd.dwFileAttributes &FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
                                    {
                                        //EnterCriticalSection(&QueueLock);
                                        subdir.push_front(subpath + "\\" + ffd.cFileName);
                                        //LeaveCriticalSection(&QueueLock);
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {   
                                        //EnterCriticalSection(&StoreLock);
                                        file->push_back(subpath + "\\" + ffd.cFileName);
                                        Files++;
                                        //LeaveCriticalSection(&StoreLock);
                                    }
                            }
                        }while(FindNextFileA(hfind,&ffd));
                        FindClose(hfind);
                        hfind = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
                    }
            }
            //subdir.clear();
            //directories.clear();
            //cout <<endl<<file->size();
            cout<<" No of Files  "<<Files <<endl ;
            //display(files);
            //subdir.clear();
            //HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, list);
            return 0;
        }
}
```

TestList.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include "MultiDrive List.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace DriveFiles;

int main()
{
    string drv;

    //vector<string>files;
    ofstream out;
    //List *list;

    cout << "\n Enter the Id of Drives to list " <<endl;

    getline(cin,drv);

    FileList :: ListFiles(drv);

    extern struct DriveFiles::List *list;

    /*for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        cout <<endl<< list->files[i].size();*/

    //cout<<"Listed";

    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {

        //while(k< list->files[i].size())
        //{
        //cout <<endl<< list->files[i].size();
            out.open("Lists.txt",ios_base::out | ios_base::app );
            vector<string>::iterator it = list->files[i].begin();
            if(list->files[i].size()!=0)
            do
            {
                //cout << "Writing to .txt File ";
                out<<*it<<endl;
                *it++;
                //k++;
            }while(it!=list->files[i].end());
            out.close();
        //}
        //list->files[i].clear();
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

My code is so long as the MultiDrive List.h and MultiDriveListing.cpp froms a static .lib library.The TestList.cpp is the program which accesses the library to get the output and prints it.please any improvements and help is welcomed.

Comment: Would it be facile of me to suggest that you do some debugging? Do you know how to? My belief is that your real problem is that you've not yet learnt how to do that. It will be easier to make progress in the future if you learn to debug.

Comment: I would also point out that your code leaks rather badly. Try to wean yourself off new and use the standard containers. I am reluctant to dig deeper because there's just so much code here. Can't you cut it down? That would help your debugging too.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan..I debugged so only i told am having this problem.Since it is showing error at random lines in my problem am unable to find where exactly the error occurs.please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Although there are several problems with your code (leaks being one of them), a quick look makes me suspect your iterator increment in this block of code. Try the following change:

```
do
{
    out<<*it<<endl;
    ++it;          // <----- this line changed
}while(it!=list->files[i].end());
```

Comment: ...Thanks for pointing.but actually the error happens during execution of MultiDriveListing.cpp.I don't know where exactly the error occurs.

Comment: Thanks..But please help me changing the other problems too as i don't know exactly where error occuring.

Comment: @WarriorPrince Well in your question you say *"I don't know where the error is"* and now you say *"the error happens during execution of MultiDriveListing.cpp"*, you need to give us all of the information that you have obtained from your debugging. Just like David Heffernan said, I'm also reluctant to debug such a large code dump.

Comment: ..I don't know where exactly the error happens with MultiDriveListing.cpp..That is what am trying to say

Answer (score 0):

I suspect its the usage of

```
(char*)s
```

across multiple thread.